# Django: Overriding Model.save() causing IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, super

I'm trying to override the save method on a model to make sure that new instances get a many-to-many field populated correctly. The first thing I do in my overridden method is call the super() save method. But somehow this is causing an Integrity Error. Any thoughts?

```
File: models.py
class Bill(models.Model): 
''' A shared bill '''
total_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
description = models.CharField(max_length=80)
fronting_user = models.ForeignKey(BillsUser,
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                related_name='fronted_bill_set')
splitting_users = models.ManyToManyField(BillsUser,
                                         related_name='split_bill_set',
                                        through='BillShare',
                                        through_fields=('bill', 'owed_by'))
group = models.ForeignKey(BillsGroup)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        is_new_instance = True
    super(Bill, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    if is_new_instance:
        members = self.group.users.all()
        for bu in members:
            amount = (payer_share_amt(total_cost, len(members)) 
                        if bu == self.fronting_user
                      else share_amt(total_cost, len(members)))
            BillShare.objects.create(owed_by=bu,
                                     owed_to=self.fronting_user,
                                     total_amount=amount,
                                     amount_unpaid=amount)
```

Traceback from trying to save an unchanged instance in the admin view:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/bills/bill/3/change/

Django Version: 1.9.2
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['bills',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: bills_bill.id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
541.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
244.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
1440.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in inner
30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
1378.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
991.         obj.save()

File "/media/sf_Dropbox/python/projects/phoenixbills/phoenixbills/bills/models.py" in save
57.         super(Bill, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
851.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
1060.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/bills/bill/3/change/
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: bills_bill.id
```

Comment: Don't pass `self` as an argument when using `super()`.

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake.